# Does TortoiseHg allow you to see the command line output?

Tags: tortoisehg

Is there a feature or log function in TortoiseHg that will allow you to see the results of a command issued from the gui?

For example, if you sent a commit with the GUI I'd like to see the Hg command issue

hg commit -m "This was my commmit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in some cases.
For example the synchronize window shows cli output.

Comment: What about something like creating a named branch?

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can do named branches from tortoisehg

Comment: This answer is true for the linux version of TortoiseHg, not for the Windows version.

Comment: you can create named branches from TortoiseHg. In the commit dialog, there is a button just below the commit button, that lets you affect a branch name to the commited changeset.

Comment: @barjak : I must have missed that, anyway, after looking around a bit, I have only found the cli output in the synchronize window.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, its part of the new 2.0 version of TortoiseHg, its available on the TortoiseHg Workbench, and the option is called "Show Output Log"

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/whatsnew.html